# PyQt animate QGraphicsItem not working

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

I'm using Python 2.7 with PyQt 4.0.

I'm trying to make a QGraphicsRectItem move 10 px up in a animation. I have read the documentation and several tutorials but I can't get it to work. What is wrong with my code?

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import random

class TestWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.view = QGraphicsView(self.scene)
        self.button1 = QPushButton("Do test")
        self.button2 = QPushButton("Move forward 10")

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        buttonLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.button1)
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.button2)
        buttonLayout.addStretch()
        layout.addWidget(self.view)
        layout.addLayout(buttonLayout)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.do_test)
        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.move_forward)

    def do_test(self):
        self.turtle = self.scene.addRect(0,0,10,20)

    def move_forward(self):
        animation = QGraphicsItemAnimation()
        timeline = QTimeLine(1000)
        timeline.setFrameRange(0,100)
        animation.setTimeLine(timeline)
        animation.setItem(self.turtle)
        animation.setPosAt(1.0, QPointF(self.turtle.x(),self.turtle.y()+10))
        timeline.start()
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this small change (in function move_forward).

replace

```
animation = QGraphicsItemAnimation()
```

with

```
animation = QGraphicsItemAnimation(self)
```

that changes the behaviour for me.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why your example doesn't work, is that you are not keeping a reference to the `QGraphicsItemAnimation` created in the `move_forward` method, and so it gets garbage-collected before it has a chance to do anything.

I would suggest you create the animation in `__init__` so that you can access it later as an instance attribute:

```
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    ...
    self.animation = QGraphicsItemAnimation()

def move_forward(self):
    timeline = QTimeLine(1000)
    timeline.setFrameRange(0, 100)
    self.animation.setTimeLine(timeline)
    self.animation.setItem(self.turtle)
    self.animation.setPosAt(
        1.0, QPointF(self.turtle.x(), self.turtle.y() + 10))
    timeline.start()
```